# What Arcane spells can actually hit multiple targets with a Spell Attack (for Spell Swipe)?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, magus

For the [Magus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=17), [Spell Swipe](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2866) (and eventually [Whirlwind Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2885)) allows you to hit multiple enemies with a [Spellstrike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=755); however, if you actually want your multiple targets to both get hit by a spell, you need a spell that can target multiple creatures with a Spell Attack roll*:

> If your spell could affect two or more targets, your spell affects whichever foes you hit, not just the first target; otherwise, choose one target to affect with the spell.

The only spell I'm aware of that targets multiple creatures with a Spell Attack roll is [Scorching Ray](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=992). Are there any **other** spells that could work with this? Preferably also not focus spells that I'd have to take a dedication to get to (i.e. Magus focus spells are fine, but Domain focus spells not so much).

*I'm aware [Expansive Spellstrike](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2849) increases the options (adding, importantly, [Electric Arc](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=97) and [Scatter Scree](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=990)), but I'm hoping to take a different feat at level 2 and don't want to have to make room for it in my build.

Comment: The more I look at Magus, the more important it seems to have Expansive Spellstrike haha

Comment: @Ifusaso Yep, guess I'm making room for it. Scorching Ray does scale up rather nicely, but I hate relying on fire damage...

Comment: You may be interested in Overwhelming Spellstrike and/or Cascading Ray at later levels (instead of trying to fit in Expansive). It's worth remembering that probably 70-80%+ of your Spellstrikes are going to be Cantrips with how Magi spell slots work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There is currently no other* multiple attack Arcane spell

*Not counting Horizon Thunder Sphere's AoE because it's not valid with Spellstrike

I couldn't think of a good way to parse this, but realized a relatively simple way: the Spells section of the [[Attack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=15)] trait has what *should be* a full list of spells, which is fairly limited (for now) that involve attack rolls. Going through them, the ones typically available in Arcane are:

- Acid Arrow (single target)
- Acid Splash (single)
- Admonishing Ray (single)
- Chromatic Ray (single)
- Disintegrate (single)
- Gouging Claw (single)
- Horizon Thunder Sphere (single plus AoE if cast over 2 rounds)
- Hydraulic Push (single)
- Magnetic Acceleration (single)
- Polar Ray (single)
- Produce Flame (single)
- Ray of Enfeeblement (single)
- Ray of Frost (single)
- Scorching Ray (multiple, as noted in Q)
- Shocking Grasp (single)
- Snowball (single)
- Tanglefoot (single)
- Telekinetic Maneuver (single)
- Telekinetic Projectile (single)

Comment: That is a smart way to go about it... and also produces the answer I both expected and hoped was untrue. Thank you though!!

Comment: @ESCE I'm hoping the future-proofing was intentional and we'll see more valid spells for Magus coming down the pipes... but only a little considering the sparse options (for them) added in their own book *about magic*